# SignalR using server-sent event on Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, signalr

My Problem:

I am running my code on Chrome, notice that SignalR is using html5 `server-sent events` as an automatic choice, great. However, when I refresh the page `onDisconnect()` on server side doesn't fire until 30 seconds later. Is there any settings in the `Hub` I can do to make it response upon the disconnect event immediately?

My Observation:

Note that delay issue only happens with I refresh page, not when I am closing the browser. The `onDisconnect()` fires instantly when closing the browser. Strange thing @_@

Version Limitation:

I am using SignalR 1.1.3 (The latest version before 2.x.x happened) because we don't have vs2013 in our company and I couldn't get 2.x.x to work with vs2013 express on my pc anyway.

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. One that we struggle with everytime a new version of a browser comes out we need to verify that thing still work. Here's the outstanding bug for that issue https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2719

Comment: thanks very much for the link dfowler :) Is it stable under version 2.xx now?

Comment: It's a bug in chrome. We're actually not fixing anything.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR sends an ajax request to `OnDisconnected` in the `window.unload` event to notify the server it aborted the connection. This ajax request may not complete before the document unloads if it is asynchronous, or it may simply not get executed by the browser at all. This behavior often seems to change between different browser versions; I've seen this fail in various versions of Chrome and Firefox. In SignalR 2.x, the script also tries to stop the connection in onbeforeunload; I'm not sure if that completely resolves the issue.

If said ajax call doesn't complete, `OnDisconnected` is only called after the [disconnect timeout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout) (30s by default). You can change this setting via:

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

You could try modifying the SignalR script so it always uses `async: false` when aborting from window.unload, which may increase the odds of the call completing in your scenario. However, doing a synchronous call from window.unload may also be considered bad practice by the browser because it can potentially keep the page from unloading. So the browser may decide to not allow such a call. I'm having the same problem with SignalR 2.0-rc1 in a self-hosted cross-domain setup and haven't been able to find a good solution so far. So, ultimately it seems like it may not be wise to rely on an immediate call to `OnDisconnected` at all.

One issue that I've noticed is that if you start the hub connection with `jsonp: true`, it won't notify the server at all even if you close the tab - in that case, setting the ajax call's dataType to "text" will at least be a partial fix.

I see there is a more authorative answer now, but I'm posting this anyway.

Edit:

Using this here

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
};
```

works quite well, actually.

Comment: currently we just ignore it, but I will give it a try as soon as I get back to that part of the project, thank you :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Unfortunately, it is on IE8, where jsonp is required. `window.onbeforeunload` does not work for me either. Are you saying that it is possible to modify a single method call to use `async: false`? Any more details you can provide about that?

Comment: @murrayju What I meant was that you can make the call that triggers OnDisconnected synchronous; you could do that (conditionally) in jquery.signalr-*; the relevant method's name is "ajaxAbort"; however, I wouldn't recommend that approach if you can avoid it with a different design