# HitCounter for SignalIR not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, signalr

I have just started with SignalIR and tried to work with a sample code for hitcounter.
Following is the code I am using :
http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/get-the-number-of-users-that-are-online-using-signalr/1095

What I see is:
- On Chrome if I refresh the page it increases the counter which is not for FF and IE
- If I open the page on separate tab even on FF and IE the counter increases.

I think,

```
clientId = Context.ConnectionId;
```

Is not working properly - or not sure if that is how it should work - but I need to know if there is any way I can count the unique hits - when ever a browser session is open it should count 1 and doesn't increase until the broser session is closed.

Comment: i think you have to post more code, with such less code, can't say exactly where is the issue?

Comment: Hi @Jai I am using the code in the link in my post.

Comment: if that is the case then i think this issue is browser specific. May be the specific version of chrome.

Comment: @Jai : Any work around ?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're seeing is probably related to [this bug](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2719) in Chrome (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533189/signalr-using-server-sent-event-on-chrome)). In FF and IE, it will call `OnDisconnected` before the new connection is established, but in Chrome, `OnDisconnected` will only get called after a timeout, so when you establish the new connection, the old one will still be in the `Users` list (and thus your counter will increase).

Comment: Hopper : Thanks a lot for references; Do you please know of any work around ?

Comment: OnDisconnected will get called eventually, so the count will only be wrong until then; you can also use the workaround mentioned in the issue tracker (window.onbeforeunload = ...)