# MVC 5 application with AJAX and SignalR hangs in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a MVC 5 application that uses AJAX calls and SignalR. The application hangs in Chrome when the following order of actions get executed:

1. User visits Page A and after the page has loaded the console looks like this

   ```
   SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
   SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint
   SignalR: EventSource connected.
   SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.
   SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
   SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
   ```
2. User clicks on a link of Page A that invokes an AJAX call
3. The AJAX call from 2. returns successfully and the UI is updated via jQuery
4. User initiates a page refresh via F5 and after the page has loaded the console looks like this

   ```
   SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
   SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint
   SignalR: EventSource connected.
   SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.
   ```
5. User tries to navigate by clicking a simple link (a tag with href attribute) and the site hangs for roughly 2 minutes until the new page is served

I noticed that after 4. the console does not show the

```
SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of ...
```

lines, so it has something do to with SignalR i guess.

Has anyone encountered such a huge delay in the past and knows how to avoid it?

I have tried

- changing transport protocol of SignalR
- the [window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20534796/3936440) workaround
- different jQuery versions
- 1000 other things i can't remember already

Any help is greatly appreciated as i'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @Dimitry Nope, couldn't find a way thus sadly needed to remove SignalR functionality

Comment: Check this link, it may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668835/debugging-signalr-hang

Comment: This might also be an issue here: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/5975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was posted while using Orchard. After updating Orchard to 1.10.1 the timeouts are gone and SignalR works perfectly in Chrome now.

I inspected each code file while updating to 1.10.1 and there were some changes in the Owin and session stuff, so i suppose it was an issue with the Owin or session implementation / handling.